# Floating menu after fold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that shows a floating fixed menu based on height e.g. after 1000px.

I want to alter this to show after the fold of the page.

Code below

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var $top1= $('#headerBackgroundWhite').offset().top + 1000;   
var $mid1 =  Math.floor($(window).height() / 2);
$('#dirbutton').data('mode','scrollup');




$('#dirbutton').click(function()
{
   $mode = $(this).data('mode');

   switch($mode)
   {
     case 'scrolldown':
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
     return false;
     break;
 case 'scrollup':
    $scrollpos = $('body').outerHeight();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$scrollpos}, 'slow');
    return false;
    break;
   }


});

$(window).scroll(function()
{   

    if ($(window).scrollTop()>$top1)   
    {
     $('#headerBackground').hide();
     $('#headerBackgroundWhite').show();
     $('#headerBackgroundWhite').addClass('floater');
    }
    else
    {
     $('#headerBackgroundWhite').hide();
     $('#headerBackground').show();

     }



});
```

I have attempted to alter the third line to end + window to take the window height but without success.

Any advice on how this can be done?

Comment: Create a jsFiddle or Plunkr.  There's too much guessing as to your markup and other details that make it difficult to determine the solution / give you a good answer.

Comment: jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/62e7dnhm/3/